# Fields still contain form data when new model instance is passed to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partialviews

I have a partialview which post to server using jquery. The posting is working. However, when returning, I am returning partialviewresult with blank model (new model), but the return HTML is still containing the data previously post. Any idea on clearing the data on the return?

```
$("#btnSend").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#frmCompose').valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("PartialCompose", "Message")',
        dataType: "html",
        data: $('#frmCompose').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#divTab2").html(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, s, e) {
            alert('Error');
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
        });
    }        
});
```

Here is the Action:

```
    [SessionExpireFilterAttribute]
    [HttpPost] // POST: /message/partialcompose
    public PartialViewResult PartialCompose(_MessageExt model)
    {
        _MessageExtDAL __DAL = new _MessageExtDAL(base.LoginTimeZoneMin);
        try
        {
            model.MessageId = 0;
            model.AccountId = base.LoginUser.AccountId;
            model.EditBy = base.LoginUser.UserId;

            __DAL.Send(model, Config.SQLConn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.Prompt = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            __DAL = null;
        }
        return PartialView(new _MessageExt());
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the action as well?

Comment: I have checked the result return to jquery, the input textfield still have the value.

Comment: `return PartialView(new _MessageExt);` does this compile?

Comment: Sorry typo, the original code should be: 
return PartialView(new _MessageExt());

Comment: I have reworded your title to make it more easily identifiable to those having the same problem in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are returning the same view directly from the POST action and the form values still exist in `ModelState`.

This is by design, primarily for the purpose of displaying validation errors in conjunction with the original form data. Values in `ModelState` have a *higher precedence* than those in the model object passed to the view, so if both exist, the values in `ModelState` will be used.

The following should see the fields cleared:

```
ModelState.Clear();
return PartialView(new _MessageExt());
```